# How to install grub on Windows 10 (dual boot with CentOS)?

Tags: dual-boot, grub

I have Windows 10 dual boot with CentOS. However, I can't access CentOS, my machine start automatically with Windows, and there is no Grub screen to choose CentOS. Can you guys help me? Thanks.

Comment: Does the system use legacy/BIOS or UEFI? In which order did you install the OS's?

Comment: Even more questions: When not BIOS, is it UEFI (PC) or EFI (e.g. Mac)? Which CentOS? Did you actually install grub without errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a Tutorial on the installation of Grub on CentOS 7:

## Dual Boot Installation with Grub

Installation of Grub2 and dual boot with windows 10

If your Grub configuration is not as you like follow this tutorial.
First reinstall Grub.

```
sudo yum reinstall grub2-tools
```

Login as root in a terminal

```
su
```

In another terminal , get information about your Windows 10 hard drive, in my case it was named '/dev/sdb1'

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

In my configuration, my windows 10 disk was on another hard drive. **Follow only if you are in the same situation.**

In the root terminal, navigate to the grub configuration directory

```
 cd  /etc/grub.d/
```

Now we must find the UUID of your Windows 10 hard drive, enter this command in your non-root terminal

```
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

Find the UUID code next to your disk something like: 40S863A9D8619F12

Now in the root terminal enter the command:

```
nano 40_custom
```

Inside this file enter your windows 10 configuration using GRUB standard. Use the UUID code previously found inside the configuration. In my case my config is:

```
menuentry 'Windows 10' {
        insmod ntfs
        insmod ntldr
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod search_fs_uuid
        search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 40S863A9D8619F12
        ntldr /bootmgr
}
```

Save and exit nano. Now we need to generate a new GRUB configuration file. Enter the command:

```
grub2-mkconfig --output=/boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Voilà !!!! Try the configuration with a fresh restart

Source:
http://dareneiri.github.io/Configuring-Grub-2-on-CentOS-7/
https://ihaveabackup.net/article/grub2-entry-for-windows-10-uefi

### (Optional) Install GRUB customizer

If you want to have a sexy GRUB menu you can install grub-customizer using this tutorial:
https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/grub-customizer-5.0.6-1.el7.x86_64.rpm.html

you can find more tutorial at: https://github.com/Winterhart/CentOS7-Setup/